# cell.detaillabel's text not shown

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableView in which I need to show `textlabel` and `detailtextlabel`.

But `detailtextlabel` is not shown.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
     UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if(cell == nil){
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
      }

      NSMutableDictionary *d2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[autocompleteUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

      cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[d2 valueForKey:@"FLName"]];
      cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Id";
      cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
      cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;

      return cell;
}
```

But `detailtextlabel` is not shown, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use UITableViewCellStyleDefault but you have to use UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` in this case

```
[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]
```

Answer (score -1):

To give you answer in details :

[image][image]